# update part of string in database when condition meets

Tags: mysql

[image]

This is my database structure. I want to update **mobileno** column where `length(mobileno)!= 13`  , and add **88** string before them . Like **017126875493** becomes **88017126875493**

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `concat()`

```
UPDATE tablename SET mobileno = concat('88',mobileno)
WHERE length(mobileno) != 13;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using concat()

```
UPDATE passenger.mobileno
SET passenger.mobileno= CASE
   WHEN length(passenger.mobileno)=11 THEN CONCAT("88",passenger.mobileno)
   ELSE passenger.mobileno
```